# Why can't I move my transform widget in Blender

Tags: transforms

I am new here and I was following an online blender tutorial. After I followed every step, I cann't move the transform widget to the direction I want. I am stuck here and I don't want to jump to another video until I understand everything.
Please help me.

Thank you in advance[image][image]

Comment: It's not a cursor bro. It's a gizmo. Click on the tip of the arrow and it will let you do things to your object. Right click on 2.79, left click on 2.80

Comment: It's a dummy that is centered around the object.

Comment: [Transformation Manipulators](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/manipulators.html)